# View from 2 tables and 2 record from another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table SOME_TABLE with column SOME_ID.
I also have table ANOTHER_TABLE with column SOME_TABLE_SOME_ID (FOREIGN KEY), TYPE, CONTENT

There is 1 or 2 records in ANOTHER_TABLE for one record in SOME_TABLE.

I would like to have view as below:

```
SOME_ID, CONTENT_TYPE_A, CONTENT_TYPE_B
```

I have sql statement:

```
SELECT
ST.SOME_ID,
TYPE_A.CONTENT CONTENT_TYPE_A, 
TYPE_B.CONTENT CONTENT_TYPE_B
FROM SOME_TABLE ST
LEFT OUTER JOIN ANOTHER_TABLE TYPE_A
ON ST.SOME_ID=TYPE_A.SOME_TABLE_SOME_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ANOTHER_TABLE TYPE_B
ON ST.SOME_ID=TYPE_B.SOME_TABLE_SOME_ID 
WHERE
TYPE_A.TYPE = 'A'
AND
TYPE_B.TYPE = 'B'
```

This query returns only results for SOME_TABLE if both records in ANOTHER_TABLE exist (with TYPE='A' and TYPE='B').

How to get view when for corresponding SOME_TABLE record exist only 1 record in ANOTHER_TABLE?

I would like to have null value in CONTENT_TYPE_A or CONTENT_TYPE_B when there is now record.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
SELECT
ST.SOME_ID,
TYPE_A.CONTENT CONTENT_TYPE_A, 
TYPE_B.CONTENT CONTENT_TYPE_B
FROM SOME_TABLE ST
LEFT OUTER JOIN ANOTHER_TABLE TYPE_A
ON ST.SOME_ID=TYPE_A.SOME_TABLE_SOME_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ANOTHER_TABLE TYPE_B
ON ST.SOME_ID=TYPE_B.SOME_TABLE_SOME_ID 
WHERE
TYPE_A.TYPE = 'A'
OR
TYPE_B.TYPE = 'B'
```